# Failed to compile python (Permission denied!) while deploying some changes in heroku

Tags: python, git, heroku, git-bash

I have deployed a project of github in heroku. Then I successfully cloned the project with my pc using   `heroku slugs:download -a newocas`

Now, after making some changes and doing commit while deploying the project back to heroku produces the same error again and again.

I'm using `git bash` for commit and deploy. Here's my error messages:

```html
Sultan@Sultan-PC MINGW32 ~/newocas/app (master)
$ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 133, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (125/125), done.
Writing objects: 100% (133/133), 2.93 MiB | 229.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 133 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: /app/tmp/buildpacks/779a8bbfbbe7e1b715476c0b23fc63a2103b3e4131eda558669aba8fb5e6e05682419376144189b29beb5dee6d7626b4d3385edb0954bffea6c67d8cf622fd51/bin/steps/python: line 43: /app/.heroku/python/bin/pip: Permission denied
remote: -----> Installing pip
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote:        /app/tmp/buildpacks/779a8bbfbbe7e1b715476c0b23fc63a2103b3e4131eda558669aba8fb5e6e05682419376144189b29beb5dee6d7626b4d3385edb0954bffea6c67d8cf622fd51/bin/steps/pip-install: line 5: /app/.heroku/python/bin/pip: Permission denied
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy....
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to newocas.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/newocas.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/newocas.git'
```

and here's my **requirement.txt** file

`Flask==0.10.1
 future==0.16.0`

I have tried  this - [Pip not found when deploying Django app to Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23895291/pip-not-found-when-deploying-django-app-to-heroku)
, this- [Push rejected, failed to compile Python app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22998190/push-rejected-failed-to-compile-python-app),  this- [Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Python/django app (Python 2.7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13896736/heroku-push-rejected-failed-to-compile-python-django-app-python-2-7?rq=1)  and this - [Heroku/python failed to detect set buildpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39282911/heroku-python-failed-to-detect-set-buildpack)

But still the error occurs!!!

Could someone help me in this reagard

Comment: Anything in `heroku logs` ?

Comment: Build failed in heroku logs. And the same kind of error appears there also @bren

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem. I'm sharing the procedure below:

Firstly, using `heroku slugs:download -a newocas` will not work in that case. When the app has been downloaded using slugs then it couldn't be linked to heroku afterwards.

**So, the solution is to clone the app in the pc using git bash and then after any changes make a commit and then push the changes to heroku app.**

[image]